# python 7zip script works for a while then closes randomly

Tags: python, windows, 7zip

This python script goes into all subdirectories and zips all the folders individually into a .zip using 7zip. Then it deletes the orginal folder and logs the directory it has deleted in a text file.

But when I run the script for about a few minutes after it has gone through about 7 or so subdirectories it will work fine up until it will randomly close while and there is still another 400 subdirectories to go so not sure why it just closes.

I checked my CPU/memory usage and its very low usage since its going through each folder one by one with no compression set.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Is there something that is causing the error in this python script?

```
import os
import subprocess
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

parent_dir = "D:/directory/"
log_file = Path(r"C:\logfolder\7Zip log.txt")
for subdir in os.listdir(parent_dir):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(parent_dir, subdir)
    if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):
        for subsubdir in os.listdir(subdir_path):
            subsubdir_path = os.path.join(subdir_path, subsubdir)
            if os.path.isdir(subsubdir_path):
                zip_filename = subsubdir_path + ".zip"
                subprocess.run(["7z", "a", "-r", "-mx0", "-tzip", zip_filename, subsubdir_path])
                if os.path.exists(zip_filename):                   
                    shutil.rmtree(subsubdir_path)
                    print(f"Deleted {subsubdir_path}.")
                    with log_file.open(mode='a') as f:
                        f.write(f"Deleted {subsubdir_path}.\n")
                else:
                    print(f"Zip file {zip_filename} was not created.")
                    with log_file.open(mode='a') as f:
                        f.write(f"Zip file for {subsubdir_path} was not created.\n")
input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

Comment: What's the structure of the directory being zipped?  It looks like this code only goes a couple of subdirectories deep.  Also it is a bad idea to alter an iterable (in this case the directory tree) while iterating over it, which is likely the problem.

Comment: The structure is D:/directory/ being the main
D:/directory/folder1/folder1/
D:/directory/folder2/folder1/
D:/directory/folder3/folder1/
Then in these direcories are files. In the script it will zip up the 2nd subdirecory folder "folder1" then delete it after it has zipped them


I want it to only go 2 subdirecory deep is what it currently does.


May I know what you mean by alter an iterable directory tree while iterationg over it? And how can I make the changes as it seems to be a simple function using "for" loop

Comment: @MarkTolonen. I don't think that's the problem (though I don't know what the problem actually is.) The function `os.listdir` returns an actual list. Once you have the list, changes to the underlying directory structure won't affect the list.

Comment: @FrankYellin True, then no idea either.

Comment: Run your script from CMD and get a trace. My guess is `rmtree` fails on read-only files or locked files or hidden files or something else. Read about `ignore_errors` argument.

Comment: I have checked and all the files and folders have read only set to disabled, none have been locked or hidden. I have inspected the files/folder it stops at but see no reason why it has stopped there and when I run the script again it continues without issue for a fre minutes before closing again.

Comment: looks like the issue was I had to use unicode encoding for text when writing to the logfile and the filename/foldername has unicode characters in them

Comment: I'm surprised that that caused the program to suspend and not give you any error messages.